# Proper way to find newest file in a directory

Tags: java, file, file-system, io, stream

I wanted to ask if this is a better way to find a latest file in given directory. This is my current approach:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FilesOperations {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Set<Path> pathSet = getFilesFromDirectory("C:some/path/");

        iteratePaths(pathSet);

        getLatestFile(pathSet);
    }

    public static Set<Path> getFilesFromDirectory(String directory) {

        Set<Path> pathSet = new HashSet<>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(test\\d-)(\\d{12})(\\.txt)");
        Path lookUpPath = Paths.get(directory);

        Stream<Path> stream = null;
        try {
            stream = Files.find(lookUpPath, 1, (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
                File file = path.toFile();
                return !file.isDirectory() && pattern.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
            });

            stream.forEach(path -> {
                pathSet.add(path);
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stream.close();
        return pathSet;
    }

    public static void iteratePaths(Set<Path> pathSet) {
        pathSet.stream().forEach(path -> {
            System.out.println(path);
        });
    }

    public static Path getLatestFile(Set<Path> pathSet) throws IOException {

        long fileTime = 0;
        Path pathToReturn = null;
        BasicFileAttributes attr = null;

        for (Path path : pathSet) {
            attr = getBasicFileAttributes(path);
            if (attr.creationTime().toMillis() > fileTime) {
            fileTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
                pathToReturn = path;
            }
        }

        attr = getBasicFileAttributes(pathToReturn);
        System.out.println("Latest file: " + pathToReturn + " - " + attr.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
        return pathToReturn;
    }

    private static BasicFileAttributes getBasicFileAttributes(Path pathToReturn) throws IOException {
        BasicFileAttributes attr;
        attr = Files.readAttributes(pathToReturn, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        return attr;
    }

}
```

I know this is quite simple without any sophisticated solutions, but it works. I hope you can point some places for improvements. If you have some ideas, how to refactor code to use more streams, it would be great (e.g. in `getLatestFile()` ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some minore issues only...

### naming / return type

`public static Path getLatestFile()` assumes that you return only **ONE** file, but it's easily possible that you have two files of the same date... so you should maybe return a `Set<Path>` from your method `getLatestFiles()`. This method would return **all** files with the latest time stamp.

### use a logging framework

you should write infos into a proper logging stream:

```
System.out.println("Latest file: " + pathToReturn + " - " + attr.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
```

### note:

you could write the corresponding information **directly** inside the loop.

```
for (Path path : pathSet) {
        attr = getBasicFileAttributes(path);
        if (attr.creationTime().toMillis() > fileTime) {
        fileTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
            pathToReturn = path;
            //here
            System.out.println("Latest file: " + pathToReturn + " - " + attr.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
        }
    }

    //instead of here:
    //attr = getBasicFileAttributes(pathToReturn);
    //System.out.println("Latest file: " + pathToReturn + " - " + attr.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
```

### more significant code (tell, don't ask):

maybe it's just my style but i would really directly return what is said:

```
private static BasicFileAttributes getBasicFileAttributes(Path pathToReturn) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAttributes(pathToReturn, BasicFileAttributes.class);
}
```

### use a test case

instead of testing your code in a main-methode write a junit test. that makes the code clearer to read and you can get rid of the methods `getFilesFromDirectory()` and `iteratePaths()` which are only for testing.

ever since the test methods are still in review let me advise you about these:

### possible NPE

it's possible to create a `NullPointerException`:

```
Stream<Path> stream = null;
try {...} catch (IOException e) {...}
//if an exception is raised within this block above an NPE will be thrown!
stream.close();
```

maybe you could consider a try-with-resources block? maybe you don't care because it's a mere test method, haha =)

### use a Logger / Handle Exceptions

what do you do if an exception really happens? you should implement the actions that should happen in case of exception - not just printing to stacktrace:

```
Stream<Path> stream = null;
    try {...} catch (IOException e) {
        //don't print - take actions instead!
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

as said above, maybe you don't care because it's a mere test method...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advices. In this particular case, I don't expect more then one file from the exact same time, but in more general approach it is a very good idea. I was writing this in hurry, thats why there are no loggers and exceptions handling - but yes - this are must have. Regarding NPE, I will think about `Optional` (I have no idea right now if it is possible for `Stream`. Thank you for your time, to explaining the topic in details.

Comment: @Fangir thank **you** very much for sharing your code!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you'll be using the regular expression pattern for other things it can be simplified by removing the unnecessary brackets. Also since it never changes it would make sense to keep it as a constant in the class. A better name would also be a good idea:

```
private static final Pattern FILENAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("test\\d-\\d{12}\\.txt");
```

Setting `stream` to null runs the danger that `stream.close()` will cause a `NullPointerException`, if something goes wrong. Better use "try with resources" as @MartinFrank suggests.

Instead of using `.forEach` on the stream use `.collect` to create a `Set`:

```
public static Set<Path> getFilesFromDirectory(String directory) {

    Path lookUpPath = Paths.get(directory);

    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(lookUpPath, 1, (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
        File file = path.toFile();
        return !file.isDirectory() && FILENAME_PATTERN.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
    })) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

}
```

In `getLatestFile` don't declare `BasicFileAttributes attr` outside the loop. The use after the loop is a "different" variable, so it should be declared separately.

Actually you shouldn't be be printing to `System.out` in this method at all. Either it's a debugging help, then you should be using proper logging, or it's part of the functionality to display information about the file to the user, then this should happen outside this method.

```
public static Path getLatestFile(Set<Path> pathSet) throws IOException {

    long fileTime = 0;
    Path pathToReturn = null;

    for (Path path : pathSet) {
        BasicFileAttributes attr = getBasicFileAttributes(path);
        if (attr.creationTime().toMillis() > fileTime) {
            fileTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
            pathToReturn = path;
        }
    }
    return pathToReturn;
}
```

If you need creation time (or more attributes of the file) later, then you should have the method return that too.

Answer (score 2):

Improvements:

- End-to-end use of `Stream<Path>`, avoiding reading all `Path`s into memory
- Written as a utility method (better for unit testing)
- Use of [sneaky throws](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sneaky-throws) to "downgrade" (checked) `IOException` for use in a lambda.
- NOT DONE. Cache `Pattern` once *ever*
- NOT DONE. Some level of Javadoc.
- NOT DONE. Swallow `IOException` and return `Optional.absent()`
- NOT DONE. Side-caching of attributes to avoid re-reading them

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Optional<Path> f = getLatestFile(Path.of("."), ".*\\.java");
    System.out.println(f);
  }

  public static Optional<Path> getLatestFile(Path root, String filenameRegex) throws IOException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filenameRegex);
    return Files.find(
      root,
      6,
      (p, attr) ->
        !attr.isDirectory() &&
        pattern.matcher(p.getFileName().toString()).matches())
      .max(Comparator.comparing(FilesNewest::creationTime));
  }

  private static <E extends Throwable> FileTime creationTime(Path p) throws E {
    try {
      return Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //noinspection unchecked
      throw (E)e; // Sneaky throws
    }
  }
```